# Why my site automatically scroll down?

Tags: css

Every time when I open the site it to scroll down. About 1500 pixels down. The most interesting - I have not changed anything and before this problem was not.

MODx Evo 1.0.5

http://virtual-fortune-teller.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This, in your source code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    if (document.loginfrm) document.loginfrm.username.focus();
</script>
```

...checks whether the document has a form with id "loginfrm" in it, and if so gives the "username" field [focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.focus). (Let the page load and start typing; you'll see the User field getting field out.) Since you seem unaware this even existed, I can only guess some plugin or CMS function is injecting it automatically. You'll have to determine how to remove it.

Comment: Thank you. Thanks to you I have found and corrected the problem.